# I can console.log my pokemons but I can't seed them to my database

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, pokeapi

```
const Pokemon = require('../../models/Pokemon');
const faker = require('faker-br');
const axios = require('axios');

const seedPokemon = async function () {
    let PokemonArray = [];
    let i;
    for (i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`).then(res => {
            PokemonArray.push({
                name: res.data.name,
                height: res.data.height,
                pokédex_index: res.data.id,
                pokémon_type: res.data.types[0].type.name,
                sex: faker.random.arrayElement(['male', 'female', 'non-binary']),
                photo: res.data.sprites.front_default
            })
        })
    }
    try {
        await Pokemon.sync({ force: true });
        await Pokemon.bulkCreate(PokemonArray);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
module.exports = seedPokemon;
```

What am I doing wrong? At first I could get some pokemons to my database but as I kept running the seeders over and over it just stopped working
Somebody help me plzzzz

Comment: Without any idea of what your model looks like, I can only make an assumption that the `pokédex_index` and `pokédex_type` properties might be causing some issues. I would suggest changing them to use standard unaccented characters (`pokedex_index`, `pokedex_type`) instead.

Comment: i got it fixed by simply adding an await in front of 'axios.get'
i feel stupid